# Extracting elements off an array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

Suppose we have this main:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

}
```

How could I manage to get the elements of *argv[],in order to extract some statistics off of each one(e.g letter count,numbers ,etc.)?

I have tried couple of things but didn't work(using pointers ).Eventually I tried a work-around,using **strcpy()** to copy each element of the array and that worked.
So my question is,are there other ways to achieve that?

Here's an example of my code that works:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char temp[50];
    strcpy(temp,argv[1]); //extracting the first element of the array.
```

Comment: You should show us what (and how) *didn't* work, not what worked.

Comment: "How could I manage to get the elements of `*argv[]`" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: We don't understand the difficulty. Where is it that you use `temp` where using `argv[1]` directly doesn't work?

Comment: @Joshua  How could I iterate through the each character of the argv[1] ? The point of me using strcpy() was to achieve that.

Comment: `argv[1][8]` would be the 9'th character of `argv[1]` (if exists)

Comment: @EugeneSh. That was what I was looking for. I Knew it would be something simple that i was missing.Even though I got it working,I was wondering how it can be done without using strcpy(). I didnt think the way to access a char was like a 2D array(if that is the correct way of describing it) .You can post it as an answer if you want,and I will vote for solved as soon as I can.Thanks!

Comment: @SergeBallesta: On what platform are they `const`, because I've heard of no such thing; but rather on C's origin platform they were intended to be written to and some programs used that in a way that duplicating `argv` wouldn't have worked; and the other major platforms emulated the ability to write to them even though they didn't provide the behavior involved.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'll keep that in mind,hopefully strdup is available(I'm using Unix/Posix systems).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing so is as below:

```
int main(int argc,char argv[]){
char *temp = argv;
}
```

This code will create a string named "temp" which is a copy of "argv[]". You can use to extract any stats you like without having to use the "strcopy" function.
Also, take note that I have changed the argument from
 `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
to
`int main(int argc, char argv[])`